# How can a template class be an attribute of another template class of the same type T in c++?

Tags: c++, template-classes

I have a template class **Tripla** (node for a list structure) and another template class **Lista**. I want to make them generic so they can reused in the future, however I'm not sure how to set the data type to the Tripla objects from the class Lista.

```
template <class T>
class Tripla
{
public:
     T element;
     Tripla *anterior;
     Tripla *siguente;
     Tripla();
     .................other functions/procedures
};
```

---

```
template <class T>
class Lista
{
private:
     Tripla<T> *primer;  // or would this simple be Tripla *primer??
     Tripla<T> *ultimo; 
     public:
     Lista();
    ~Lista();
     void insertar_principio(T);
     void menu();
     .................other functions/procedures
};
```

---

```
template <class T>
void Lista<T>::insertar_principio(T el)
{
if (primer == NULL)
{
    primer = new Tripla<T>; // would this be primer = new Tripla??
    ultimo = primer;
    primer->element=el;
}
else
{
    Tripla<T> *aux = primer; // would this be Tripla *aux = primer??
    primer = new Tripla;
    primer->element = el;
    aux->anterior = primer;
    primer->siguente = aux;
}
```

}

Some compilation errors include not being able to convert `Tripla*` to `Tripla<T>*` and "error C2955: 'Tripla' : use of class template requires template argument list".

I am having problems understanding how to set the same data type to both.
For example, from main.cpp, I want to have something like

```
Lista list<int>.menu()
```

and that will automatically make Tripla *primer and *ultimo work with int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some template arguments in some places. First of all:

```
Tripla *anterior;
Tripla *siguente;
```

should be:

```
Tripla<T> *anterior;
Tripla<T> *siguente;
```

And then:

```
primer = new Tripla;
```

should be:

```
primer = new Tripla<T>;
```

Also notice that there already exist a linked list (and even doubly linked list) implementation in the standard library: `std::forward_list` for singly linked lists and `std::list` for doubly linked list.